# What C#/Linq code copies all matching property name values between two objects without knowing their type?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a well known POCO class of Customer to return from my method. However, I only populate properties specified by an ever changing Expression p => new {p.id, p.name} for example, as a parameter to the method.

Somehow I need to copy all matching fields between these two objects.

```
var returnObject = IList<Customer>();
var partialFieldObject = DC.Customers.Select( expParameter); // wont know the fields

foreach( var partialRecord in partialFieldObject)
{    foreach (var property in partialRecord // Pseudo code)
     {
         returnObject[property] = property.value; // More Pseudo code
     }
}
End result is a strongly typed Customer POCO returned that only has the selected fields populated with values.
```

Comment: By "matching" I mean copy the values of all properties of the same name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some simple reflection does the trick, assuming the properties on `partialFieldObject` line up exactly (case-sensitive) with properties on `Customer`...

```
void SetProperties(object source, object target)
{
    var customerType = target.GetType();
    foreach (var prop in source.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propGetter = prop.GetGetMethod();
        var propSetter = customerType.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetSetMethod();
        var valueToSet = propGetter.Invoke(source, null);
        propSetter.Invoke(target, new[] { valueToSet });
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I had to add some null value checks, but afterward, it worked like a charm.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: this reflection works has performance leak . it's better to use Linq expression assignments , and compile it for whole application.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) - it's built to do this stuff I think

Comment: The problem is AutoMapper doesn't map when it cannot determine the type.  It sees "object" which doesn't have any properties.

Comment: @Dr.Zim Looking at the API, you can either use a generic form of the CreateMap function, or the parameter based, which lets you pass types.  So you can do `AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(source.GetType(),destination.GetType())`

Answer (score 2):

Adapting [dahlbyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54249/dahlbyk)'s accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039823), I've ended up using the following in a constructor that accepted a base-type and needed to mirror the contents:

```
var thisType = this.GetType();
foreach (var prop in baseObj.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => thisType.GetProperty(p.Name) != null))
{
    var propGetter = prop.GetGetMethod();
    var propSetter = thisType.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetSetMethod();
    if (propSetter != null)
        propSetter.Invoke(this, new[] { propGetter.Invoke(baseObj, null) });
}
```

Basically, step through each property in the `baseObj` type where `this` type has a property with a matching name, and locate the `get` method on the `baseObj` type as well as the `set` method for the matching named property on `this` type and if there is a `set` method available on `this`, invoke it using the method returned from the invocation of the `get` method on the `baseObj` type.

Works well for public & private properties of any (matching) type on both types.

*Note: You'll need a reference to `System.Linq` for the `.Where()` func in the loop*

Answer (score 1):

Not that different, just the most compact and cleanest form I found:

```
void CopyProperties(object src, object dest) {
  foreach (var source in src.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead)) {
    var prop = dest.GetType().GetProperty(source.Name);
    if (prop?.CanWrite == true)
      prop.SetValue(dest, source.GetValue(src, null), null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Should this line actually read: 

prop.SetValue(dest, source.GetValue(src, null), null);

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void CopyPropertiesTo<T, TU>(this T source, TU dest)
    {

        var sourceProps = typeof (T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanRead).ToList();
        var destProps = typeof(TU).GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanWrite)
                .ToList();

        foreach (var sourceProp in sourceProps)
        {
            if (destProps.Any(x => x.Name == sourceProp.Name))
            {
                var p = destProps.First(x => x.Name == sourceProp.Name);
                p.SetValue(dest, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Copy(object copyToObject, object copyFromObject)
{
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    FieldInfo[] fields = copyFromObject.GetType().GetFields(flags);
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
    {
        FieldInfo fromField = copyFromObject.GetType().GetField(fields[i].Name, flags);
        FieldInfo toField = copyToObject.GetType().GetField(fields[i].Name, flags);
        if(fromField != null)
        {
            toField.SetValue(copyToObject, fromField.GetValue(copyFromObject));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting only code is often not very helpful.